# Why can't I empty the file in this way?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <graphics.h>

using namespace std;

int c;
fstream file("happy.txt");

int main()
{
    file.open("happy.txt", fstream::out|fstream::in|fstream::trunc );
    file.close();  //to clear the file first
    initwindow(1000,600);
    while (true){
        c = getch();

        file.open("happy.txt");
        file.seekp(0,file.end);   
        int fileEndCursor = file.tellp(); 
        file << (char)c;  //store what the user typed into file
        file.close();
    }
}
```

But it turns out that the file is not cleared, every time the code is finished running, the content in the last run is still in the file. Please help.

Comment: do mean every time the program is run the file isn't cleared? Nothing is going to happen to happy.txt when you compile your code...

Comment: Why do you expect the code to run at *compilation time*? The file will be cleared as you *run* the actual compiled program.

Comment: sorry, i mean after the code is run

Comment: That `while(true)` is an infinite loop.

Comment: re:arun, the user can stop it by closing the window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to open it twice:

```
fstream file("happy.txt");
file.open("happy.txt", fstream::out|fstream::in|fstream::trunc );
```

The first time you try to open it in the constructor without telling it to truncate so it only opens it leaving all the content inside.
Because it's already open the 2nd call won't do anything.

Fix it by changing

```
fstream file("happy.txt");
```

to

```
fstream file;
```